# Añadir horas laborales a días de la semana y posteriormente obtenerlas

Tags: fullcalendar

buenos días estoy tratando de integrar la API de FullCalendar pero quiero poder añadir horas laborales por día y posteriormente extraerlas para su procesamiento.

Gracias y Saludos.

Comment: Hola Humberto Medina, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, basado en esto te recomiendo realizar cambios a tu pregunta, agrega lo que has intentado como base, saludos!